# Floating alongside a variable-width image

Tags: html, css

Is there a simple way in CSS to position a number of images—stacked vertically—on the right) of a variable-sized image. The variable-sized image has a `max-width` defined that should be relative to the size of the browser window (i.e. it should be as big as possible to not fall off the screen, but not bigger than the actual image pixel dimensions). To make this more difficult, the markup is such that all `<img>`s are listed as equals, i.e., the images to appear on the right are not in a separate container.

[image]

Using a markup like the following, the size of each image is about equal.

```
<ul>
<li><img/></li> <!-- the big image -->
<li><img/></li>
<li><img/></li>
etc...
</ul>
```

By request, in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2p9gR/

It would be nice to do this in pure CSS(3), I don't need to support any browsers except my own (the latest Chrome).

Oh. And I *will* accept "no" for an answer, if it is the truth.

Comment: can you create some jsfiddle please?

Comment: What did you try? Did you try to float the images? Did you try absolute positioning?

Comment: What happens if you have an image that is 800x800 and you screen is 1200px wide? then the right edge of the small images will be at 800+30+120=950px and there will be a right hand side gutter of about 250px?

Comment: Ahem, I'm sorry :). I added a jsFiddle and I'm more specific on the browsers. It's more of a theoretical question on CSS positioning/sizing actually. And @MarcAudet, yes, I don't mind a gutter on the right side. It is also possible that there are zero "small images" and the big image will just be by itself with a 'huge' gutter. To OriShuss, absolute positioning is difficult because I don't know the actual size of the largest image.

Comment: What do you mean by "not bigger than 1:1", you need to consider images with an aspect ratio like portrait versus landscape.  So a tall-skinny portrait should be at most 800px tall and a short-long landscape image should be at most 750px wide since 20% of 750px is 150px which is what is needed for the 30px gutter plus the 12px thumbnails.  I think that you can get one or the other with CSS3 but to do both, you may need some JavaScipt/jQuery to determine the aspect ratio of the image to select the correct CSS configuration.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm using some confusing terminology again, apologies, it has nothing to do with aspect ratio. What I meant is that I don't want to stretch the displayed image beyond the actual pixel dimensions (1 pixel for 1 pixel, hence my 1:1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your picture I have come up with the following solution:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/1/" /></div>
    <ul class="small-image-list">
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/sports/2/" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/sports/3/" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/sports/4/" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/sports/5/" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {padding-right:150px;}
.container .main-image {width:100%; float:left;}
.container .main-image img {width:100%; max-width:800px; max-height:800px;}
.small-image-list {list-style:none; margin:0 -150px 0 0; padding:0; width:120px; float:right;}
.small-image-list li {width:100%; overflow:hidden; padding-bottom:10px;}

@media all and (min-width: 950px) {
        /*this is optional if you want the images to stick left when the page is over 950px;*/
    .container {padding:0;}
    .container .main-image {width:800px;}
    .small-image-list {margin:0 0 0 30px; float:left;}
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t3rJp/2/)

Delete the media query if you want the large gutter

**EDIT**

Given the need for it all to be in a list you can try this:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/2/" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/sports/3/" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/sports/4/" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/120/120/sports/5/" /></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.list {list-style:none; padding:0 150px 0 0; margin:0;}
.list li {width:120px; float:right; padding:0; display:block; overflow:hidden; margin-right:-150px;clear:right; display:block;}
.list li:first-child {width:100%; float:left; margin:0; padding:0;}
.list li:first-child img {width:100%; max-height:800px; max-width:800px;}
```

[List Example](http://jsfiddle.net/t3rJp/7/)

Comment: Nice. I love that you use the padding to get `100%-150px` in stead of my ugly `80%`. That solves _one_ of my problems at least. 
However, I figured it would be possible using floats _iff_ the small images were in a separate container. What if they aren't?

Comment: Nice! But what if the first image is smaller? I don't want it to stretch beyond the actual pixel dimensions -> http://jsfiddle.net/fyn4g/

Comment: @Noio This is Pete's fiddle with small modifications. Please accept his answer.

Comment: @Pete , thanks, I really thought this was going to be impossible :D. I'm glad I could do it just in CSS. I'll probably have to face reality and break the cleanness to make it work in different browsers, but for now, here's your code in action: http://noio.github.io/2010/12/noio-argon-theme/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution.  I needed to consider two cases that depend on the aspect ratio of the large image, portrait and landscape.

**Case 1 - Portrait**

```
<ul class="portrait">
    <li class="first">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/1000" />
    </li>
    <!-- the next two images should 'float' right of the first one -->
    <li>1
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/600" />
    </li>
    <li>2
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/560" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul.portrait {
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
ul.portrait li {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    width: 120px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
ul.portrait li img {
    width: 100%;
}
ul.portrait li.first {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.portrait li.first img {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 800px;
}
```

**Case 2 - Landscape**

```
<ul class="landscape">
    <li class="first">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/500" />
    </li>
    <!-- the next two images should 'float' right of the first one -->
    <li>1
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/600" />
    </li>
    <li>2
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/560" />
    </li>
    <li>3
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/560" />
    </li>    
    <li>4
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/560" />
    </li>
    <li>5
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/560" />
    </li>
    <li>6
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/560" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul.landscape {
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
ul.landscape li {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    width: 120px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
ul.landscape li img {
    width: 100%;
}
ul.landscape li.first {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.landscape li.first img {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

It is possible to get the images appearing in the correct configuration, bit there are some limitations.

Since floats are being used, as you make the screen more narrow, the right hand thumbnails will eventually stack below the large image.  This suggests specifying a min-width for the parent `ul` containing block.

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rsqW3/

The gist of the problem is in the rule for the large image.  In the portrait case, you need to specify `height: 100%` and `max-height: 800px` and for the landscape case, you need to specify `width: 100%` and `max-width: 600px`.  You can't quite make this distinction using CSS alone.  The `calc()` value may be of some help but it is not yet widely supported.